# Java extending parameterized class

Tags: java, generics

I'm having trouble trying to figure out the following. Imagine that I have the generic class `Node<T>` for representing the nodes of a binary tree, with some methods in it.

```
    public class Node<T> {
       T info;
       Node<T> left;
       Node<T> right;

       public Node(T info) {this.info=info;}
       //and some methods
    }
```

Now I would like to add a method for `Node`s of type `Integer`, which would sum all the nodes that can be reached from the current one:

```
    public int sum(){
        int sum = this.info;
        if(this.left!=null) sum+=left.sum();
        if(this.right!=null) sum+=right.sum();
        return sum;
    }
```

I am not quite sure how to do this. I thought of creating a class that extends `Node<Integer>` and adding the method `sum` there:

```
    public class NodeOfIntegers extends Node<Integer>{
           
         public NodeOfIntegers (T info) {super();}

         public int sum(){...}
            
    }
```

but since `left` and `right` are of type `Node<Integer>` and not `NodeOfIntegers` I can't do `left.sum()` and `right.sum()`.

Is there a way to do this without redefining `left` and `right`?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `reduce` function like the `Stream` provides:

```
public static class Node<T>{

        public Node(T value, Node<T> a, Node<T> b){
            this.value = value;
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        private final Node<T> a,b;
        private final T value;

        private T reduce(T start,BinaryOperator<T> operator){
            T reduced = operator.apply(start,value);
            if(a != null)reduced = a.reduce(reduced,operator);
            if(b != null)reduced = b.reduce(reduced,operator);
            return reduced;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node<Integer> integerNode = new Node<>(4,new Node<>(4,null,null),new Node<>(2,null,null));
        System.out.println(integerNode.reduce(0, Integer::sum));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define your T as

```
class Node<T extends Number> {

}
```

then you can write the function of sum as

```
int sum() {
    int sum = this.info.intValue();
}
```

Comment: But that would prevent me from parameterizing `Node` with some types (e.g. `Node<String>`), right?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse, then you need to check in sum method if generic instance of Number or not , and then act accordingly (as you cannot sum strings) or You can parse it using Long.valueOf() something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `NodeOfInteger` class, I would define in the Node class a

```
public T combine(BinaryOperator<T> combiner) {
    T res = this.info;
    if (this.left != null) res = combine(res, this.left.combine(combiner);
    if (this.right != null) res = combine(res, this.right.combine(combiner);
    return res;
}
```

which can be used as `node.combine(Integer::sum)`, or as `node.combine(String::concat)`

(Note that this can be defined outside of the Node class if needed)